# Find index mapping between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, mapping, where-clause

Is there a nice way in `numpy` to get element-wise indexes of where each element in `array1` is in `array2`?

An example:

```
array1 = np.array([1, 3, 4])
array2 = np.arange(-2, 5, 1, dtype=np.int)

np.where(array1[0] == array2)
# (array([3]),)
np.where(array1[1] == array2)
# (array([5]),)
np.where(array1[2] == array2)
# (array([6]),)
```

I would like to do

```
np.where(array1 == array2)
# (array([3 5 6]),)
```

Is something like this possible? We are guaranteed that all entries in `array1` can be found in `array2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 :**  Use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) there to get a mask of places where matches occur and then `np.where` to get those index positions -

```
np.where(np.in1d(array2, array1))
```

**Approach #2 :** With [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
np.searchsorted(array2, array1)
```

Please note that if `array2` is not sorted, we need to use the additional optional argument `sorter` with it.

Sample run -

```
In [14]: array1
Out[14]: array([1, 3, 4])

In [15]: array2
Out[15]: array([-2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])

In [16]: np.where(np.in1d(array2, array1))
Out[16]: (array([3, 5, 6]),)

In [17]: np.searchsorted(array2, array1)
Out[17]: array([3, 5, 6])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [62]: array1 = np.random.choice(10000,1000,replace=0)

In [63]: array2 = np.sort(np.random.choice(100000,10000,replace=0))

In [64]: %timeit np.where(np.in1d(array2, array1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 483 µs per loop

In [65]: %timeit np.searchsorted(array2, array1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 40 µs per loop
```

Comment: Awesome! I've been playing with each individually, but didn't realise the key was to combine them two. Is there any benefit to either of the two approaches you're suggesting?

Comment: @pingul I would go with `np.searchsorted` if `array2` is sorted already. Adding timings soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both of the arrays will always be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way if your arrays are not too big.

```py
np.equal.outer(array1,array2).argmax(axis=1)
```

If array1 has size N and array2 has size M, this creates a temporary array of shape (N,M), therefore the above method is not recommended if you have arrays so large that it doesn't fit in memory.