# Index mapping between two sorted partially overlapping numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

I want to solve something like the problem detailed at [Find index mapping between two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373654/find-index-mapping-between-two-numpy-arrays), but where the two arrays do not necessarily contain the same set of values, although their values are unique within each array, and are sorted.

E.g. if I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5])
b = np.array([2.2, 3.0, 4.4, 6.0])
```

I want to get an array of the same length as `a` which gives the index into `b` where the matching element is, or -1 if there is no match. I.e. in this case:

```
map = np.array([-1, 0, -1, 2, -1])
```

Is there a neat, fast way to do this using `np.searchsorted`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the searchsorted indices to do a check on matches and then mask the invalid ones with the invalid-specifier. For the matching check, do `b[idx]==a` with `idx` as those indices. Hence -

```
invalid_specifier = -1
idx = np.searchsorted(b,a)
idx[idx==len(b)] = 0
out = np.where(b[idx]==a, idx, invalid_specifier)
```

Comment: I want to check why this works. Am I right in saying that you are setting the overflowed index values to 0 (`idx[idx==len(b)] = 0`), because you are guaranteed, if the array is sorted, that `b[0]` are guaranteed never to equal the values of `a` when they are at the far right of the array?

Comment: @user2667066 I know that those overflowed ones aren't the matches.So, it doesn't matter what we assign to those in `idx` as there are no corresponding matches in `a` So, that setting is just to make sure the next step indexing doesn't throw exception because of out of bounds.